# Fix formatting for long numbered aligned equations

Tags: equations, formatting, line-breaking

I have an equation which is too long to be included in a single line, yet I still want it to be numbered and somewhat centered and aligned (e.g: avoiding the second line leaving a blank space on the left before continuing). The following is my attempted input:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
     P(x)=\frac{\left(x-x_2\right)\left(x-x_3\right) \cdots\left(x-x_n\right)}{\left(x_1-x_2\right)\left(x_1-x_3\right) \cdots\left(x_1-x_n\right)} y_1+\frac{\left(x-x_1\right)\left(x-x_3\right) \ \cdots\left(x-x_n\right)}{\left(x_2-x_1\right)\left(x_2-x_3\right) \cdots\left(x_2-x_n\right)} y_2 + \]
 \[ \cdots+\frac{\left(x-x_1\right)\left(x-x_2\right) \cdots\left(x-x_{n-1}\right)}{\left(x_n-x_1\right)\left(x_n-x_2\right) \cdots\left(x_n-x_{n-1}\right)} y_n 
\end{equation}
```

And an image of the output, which only partially achieves my vision:
[image: Output]

Could anyone give a helping hand? I really appreciate it, since this is my first time working with Latex.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest employing a `multline` environment and distributing the material across three rows. I would also get rid of the 18 [!] instances of `\left` and `\right`, as the instructions do nothing productive but do mess up the spacing around the parentheses

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}\label{eq:3}
P(x)=\frac{(x-x_2)(x-x_3)  \dotsb(x-x_n)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3) \dotsb(x_1-x_n)} y_1 \\
     +\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_3) \dotsb(x-x_n)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3) \dotsb(x_2-x_n)} y_2 \\
     +\dots
     +\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2) \dotsb(x-x_{n-1})}{(x_n-x_1)(x_n-x_2) \dotsb(x_n-x_{n-1})} y_n 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    P(x) & = \frac{(x - x_2)(x - x_3) \dots (x - x_n)}{(x_1 - x_2) (x_1 - x_3) \dots (x_1 - x_n)} y_1 + \frac{(x - x_1) (x - x_3) \dots (x - x_n)}{(x_2 - x_1) (x_2 - x_3) \dots (x_2 - x_n)} y_2 \\
    & \mathrel{\phantom{=}} {} + \dots + \frac{(x - x_1)(x - x_2) \dots (x - x_{n-1})}{(x_n - x_1)(x_n - x_2) \dots (x_n - x_{n-1})} y_n
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

In the second line, `\mathrel{\phantom{=}} {}` is used so that the spacing before `+` is correct.

Comment: Unless the text block is unsually wide, the first row will spill over into the right-hand margin. Do consider spreading the full equation across three lines instead of across just two.